# How to add only non-null item to a list in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to add non null items to a List. So I do this:

```
List<Foo> foos = []
Foo foo = makeFoo()
if (foo)
    foos << foo
```

But is there a way to do it in a single operation (without using findAll after the creation of the list). Like:

```
foos.addNonNull(makeFoo())
```

Comment: There should be....  Seems silly that you need to store foo to do your check.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another alternative is to use a short circuit expression:

```
foo && foos << foo
```

The `foo` variable must evaluate to true for the second part to be evaluated.  This is a common practice in some other languages but I'd hesitate to use it widely in groovy due to readability issues and conventions.

Comment: And again, this might skip empty/zero values you wanted to add due to groovy truth

Comment: Good point.  `foo != null && foos << foo` if you want falsey values in your list.

Comment: To your point about readability, `foo && foos << foo` is also not that much shorter than `if (foo) foos << foo`, which is clearer.

Answer (score 5):

No, you'd need to use an `if`, or write your own `addNonNull` method (which just uses an `if`)

Also:

```
if( foo ) {
```

probably isn't enough, as this will skip empty strings, or `0` if it returns integers

You'd need

```
if( foo != null ) {
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer is YES! we can get rid of assigning a variable

```
Foo foo = makeFoo()//we can ditch this
```

The answer is NO we can't get rid of the condition. BUT we can make it more compact.

Here's how

```
List<Foo> foos = []
foos += (makeFoo()?:[]);
```

The trick is groovy's "+" operator which works differently based on what is to the left and what is to the right of the "+". It just so happens that if what is on the left is a list and what is on the right is an empty list, nothing gets added to the list on the left.

**Pros** are it is quick to type and compact.

**Cons** are it is not instantly obvious what is happening to most people
AND we replaced the variable assignment with an extra operation. Groovy is 
going to try to do something to List foos no matter what, it just so happens that in the second case the result of that operation gives us a desired result.